# Where am I wrong with broadcasting info from Java and receiving in Unity?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I just started working on this project and part of it is sending packages of information from an app in Java to another Unity app.

I have been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/scripts--tutorials/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity) but I have problems getting it to work and even somewhat understanding it a bit since I have not worked with Java before.

Here is the current code I have so far.

### Main Activity Class

```
package com.example.service3;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

### Sender class

```
package com.example.service3;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service
{
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private int numIntent;

// It's the code we want our Handler to execute to send data
private Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
        // the specific method which will be executed by the handler
        public void run() {
                numIntent++;

                // sendIntent is the object that will be broadcast outside our app
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

                // We add flags for example to work from background                    
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND|Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES  );

                // SetAction uses a string which is an important name as it identifies the sender of the itent and that we will give to the receiver to know what to listen.
                // By convention, it's suggested to use the current package name
                sendIntent.setAction("com.example.service3");

                // Here we fill the Intent with our data, here just a string with an incremented number in it.
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Intent "+numIntent);
                // And here it goes ! our message is send to any other app that want to listen to it.
                sendBroadcast(sendIntent);

                // In our case we run this method each second with postDelayed
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
};

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        numIntent = 0;
        // We first start the Handler
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
        handler.postDelayed(sendData, 1000);
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

### XML for Sender

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.service3"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.service3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.service3.MyService" />
</application>
```

### Receiver Class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
private static Receiver instance;
public static String text ="1";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sentIntent = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    text = "-1";
}
public static void createInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Receiver();
    }
}

}
```

### Unity Android Manifest

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"     android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name"     android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.example.receiver3.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.receiver3" ></action>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  </application>
```

I realise this is a massively large post but I simply do not know what to do at this point and am somewhat considering backing out of the project for the fact that I have no idea how to get Java to communicate with Unity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MC -- these are two *different Android apps* running on the *same Android device??*  So, basically using Android's "service" concept. Is that right?

Comment: Yea both apps are running on the same phone at the same time.

Comment: I somewhat got part of it to work, the unity plugin gets and reads the String text ="1"; I have in the receiver however it doesn't seem like the sender is working and no matter what edits I do to the unity .xml file it still prints the 1 from the receiver